Why do my RAW files from shooting RAW + JPEG appear very dark?
I was wondering do others has the same problem as I do with this option. After I take a photo with my canon 4000d using Raw + jpeg and check it out the photo on my laptop, the raw is very dark, which I can understand, but it kinda makes it pointless as it's too dark, so I'd have to only select jpeg for a photo and if I want the same photo in raw I'd have to select raw and then change the settings to equate for the darkness ?
Can I get round this ?

Related questions: Why do RAW images look worse than JPEGs in editing programs?, and Are my RAW photos underexposed?

To judge if this is the usualy jpg has internal optimization on it, while raw has not, please post a screenshot of jpg and raw side by side. This way we can say anything if that is a unusual problem. Also pleaseinclude which software you are using to view the images/render the raw,

Many cameras underexpose a bit (something around 2/3 EV) and brighten the JPEG accordingly.  This is done to reduce highlight clipping and might depend on settings of your camera.  So the RAW appearing a bit dark than the camera's JPG could be normal.  It shouldn't be much darker, though.

You may not yet be completely understanding what a raw file is.
A raw file isn't an image meant for viewing yet, it is just the data that was captured by the sensor. You didn't tell us how you are "checking out the photo on your laptop" (i.e. what software you are using). It is possible that whatever software you are using is displaying raw files after applying settings to them that make them appear very dark. Other software may use other settings, or they may be configurable; it is difficult to say what is going on because your description that you are "checking out the photo on your laptop" doesn't tell us a lot about how you are previewing them.
If you're looking for a software recommendation of image viewing software that applies sensible settings to its previews of raw files, I suggest nomacs.
A raw file is inherently meant to be processed and exported to a real image format like JPEG, WebP, TIFF; the preview you get from some piece of software is just a preview, not a final result. When you process a raw file, probably you will apply some base curve or similar setting to it that will make it appear similar to the JPEG you got from the camera.
Similar questions here:

Why does the same raw image look different in Rawtherapee than in geeqie & DSLR preview and how to get the same preview as geeqie
Darktable doesn't seem to render RAW consistently VS lightroom


thanks much help. I normally just look at my photos on the base just "Photos" app on windows. But I'll look into this.

Raw conversion/viewing/editing applications do give A representation of the data in a raw file on your screen. But we must be careful to not think they give THE representation of the data in a raw file on your screen. They don't.
The data in a raw file must be processed to present anything remotely resembling a viewable image. How that data is processed and presented on screen varies greatly from one application to another, and even within the same application depending on what default rendering settings are selected when the raw image file is first opened. That's why opening the same raw file using different applications can give radically different results.
Raw image files contain enough data to create a near infinite number of interpretations of that data that will fit in an 8-bit jpeg file.¹ Anytime you open a raw file and look at it on your screen, you are not viewing "THE raw file." You are viewing one among countless possible interpretations of the data in the raw file. The raw data itself contains a single (monochrome) brightness value measure by each pixel well. With Bayer masked camera sensors (the vast majority of color digital cameras use Bayer filters) each pixel well has a color filter in front of it that is either red, green, or blue.² For a more complete discussion of how we get color information out of the single brightness values measured at each pixel well, please see RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?
How the image you see on your monitor when you open a raw file will look is determined by how the application you used to open the file chose to interpret the raw data in the file to produce a viewable image. Each application has its own set of default parameters that determine how the raw data is processed. Since each application uses a different set of instructions to process the raw information contained in the file, each result will be different.
One of the most significant parameters is how the white balance that is used to convert the raw data is selected. Most applications have many different sets of parameters that can be selected by the user, who is then free to alter individual settings within the set of instructions used to initially interpret the data in the raw file.
¹ Sure, you could take a picture that contains a single pure color within the entire field of view. But most photos contain a wide variation of hues, tints, and brightness levels.
² Except the "red" filter is really more of a yellow-orange color, the "green" filter is more a yellowish-green color, and the "blue" filter is a violet-tinted blue color. In other words, the colors of the filters in a Bayer mask do not correspond to the three colors our RGB monitors emit and blend to reproduce the response in our retinas that many other colors do. In fact, the colors of the filters in a Bayer mask are much closer to the three colors that each of the three types of cones in our retinas are most sensitive to than they are to the three "primary" colors we use for our RGB color reproduction systems.

The probability is that you are using some setting that is intended to improve the image quality, but which only applies to the output jpeg (edited by the camera).
Cameras that have some form of highlight protection enabled (D-lighting, lighting optimizer, etc) will generally result in an underexposed raw file. Also most cameras do not combine the raw bracketed images for HDR jpegs... some of those images may be severely underexposed.
If you want the jpegs to more closely resemble the raw files, then you need to use settings that cause the camera to do less editing/changes when generating the jpegs.
Many programs can be set to automatically edit the raw file to more closely resemble the jpeg version, but IDT the Window's Photos app can.

cheers much help
